# How to replace text between two file by key number

Tags: xml

I have 2 XML files. I want to replace the text between them with a code number.

File 1:

```xml
<Text Key="94A47551">Hello World</Text>
```

File 2

```xml
<Text Key="94A47551">Hi Friend</Text>
```

I have the code number "94A47551". I won't replace the text "Hello World" from File 1 to File 2. Now File 2 will replace "Hi Friend" with "Hello World" from File 1.

Result
File 2:

```xml
<Text Key="94A47551">Hello World</Text>
```

From there, I just need to rely on code numbers to replace the text of the 2 files. Just the same code number is replacing the text.
Is there any bulk replacement tool? Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as a relational join operation and it is easily achieved in XQuery or XSLT.

In XSLT, define a key:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="Text" use="@key"/>
```

and then process the second file with a template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="Text">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('k', @Key, $file2)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

where `$file1` is a reference to the global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file1.xml')"/>
```